# Vaadin Grid: Converter$ConversionException when trying to edit

Tags: grid, vaadin, jpacontainer

I'm trying to make my grid editable  **grid.setEditorEnabled(true);**

but when I run the application and double-click on any cell it throws the following exception

```
Caused by: com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter$ConversionException: Unable to convert value of type java.lang.Integer to presentation type class java.lang.String. No converter is set and the types are not compatible.
at com.vaadin.data.util.converter.ConverterUtil.convertFromModel(ConverterUtil.java:116)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.convertFromModel(AbstractField.java:714)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.convertFromModel(AbstractField.java:699)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setPropertyDataSource(AbstractField.java:635)
```

any idea to what could be the cause? I checked this thread [here](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3288636) but I wasn't able to fix the issue

Ivy.xml

```
<!ENTITY vaadin.version "latest.release">
```

**JPAContainer 3.2.0**

(I used same structure as the container in the demo '[jpaaddressbook](https://github.com/vaadin/jpacontainer/tree/master/jpacontainer-addressbook-demo/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/jpaaddressbook)')

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I'm guessing in order to edit components of your grid you need to have String as the data source, however you have Integer in some place. You probably need to convert those integers to string explicitly before you bind them to the grid.

Comment: thanks tk12 for your response but I think this is a bug with the "latest.release" version of vaadin since it's an alpha (I figured this out when I saw the same error in the Vaadin sampler when I tried to edit the Grid there)

Comment: Is the issue solved when you used a non-alpha release?

Comment: I'm experiencing this even though I'm on the stable (7.7.13) version and I've set a proper converter for the type of my column...